# XEN kernel, CPU missing flags?

Tags: xen, 64-bit, opteron

I'm using Opteron 6386SE processor, 16 cores. It's capabilites (flags) are here: [CPU World](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-Opteron%206386%20SE%20-%20OS6386YETGGHK.html)

But when I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` (dom0 or guest), flags are missing, for example SSE3 and SSE4.

`flags      : fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mca cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt1`

Generally, the list is very short. When I check my desktop APU or Xeon processor, it contains dozens of features. Is this normal? Are missing flags something to worry about? Our users complain about performance of this machine and I worry that something bad is going on here. `htop` says all cores are there and working hard, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`xen` hides many CPU flags from the control domain, `dom0` because `dom0` itself is a virtual machine. This is a documented behavior.

From [Xen doc](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Common_Problems#How_can_I_check_if_I.27m_able_to_run_Xen_HVM_.28fully_virtualized.29_guests.3F):

> Xen dom0 is actually a virtual machine, so it doesn't see all the cpu
>   flags as Xen hypervisor is hiding some flags from dom0.